# How can I send data to admin-ajax via JS Fetch?

Tags: filters, ajax, admin

I'm trying to implement filter system in my website. I decided to make it via js. I created fetch function

```
let filters = document.querySelectorAll('.filters-item');
let pageUrl = wp.page_url;
const postsContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.column.is-half.is-offset-1');
filters.forEach( (item) => {
        item.addEventListener('change', (e) =>{
            let url = pageUrl + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

            fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'test': "sampledatatest",
                })
            }).then( function (response) {
                if(response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }
                return Promise.reject(response);
            }).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.warn('Error', error);
            });
        });
    });
```

In my functions.php file I have simple function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function'); // wp_ajax_{ACTION HERE}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');

function misha_filter_function(){
    $t = $_POST['test'];
    echo $t;

    die();
}
```

When I click on `filter` item I'm getting error 400 in my dev console. What am I missing? Is it proper way to pass the data in the form like I did? I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: Is it possible your fetch function doesn't know about your misha_filter_function() function? Like, call the action "myfilter" anywhere?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Is it proper way to pass the data in the form like I did?

If you mean the `body` part (of your `fetch()` call), then yes, it is okay.

However,

1. **You must send a query named `action`** as part of the request (e.g. via the URL like `example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=test`), so that WordPress knows what AJAX action is it and then execute the callback(s) for that specific action.

   See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/#action) for further information, but in your case, the AJAX action is `myfilter` as in `wp_ajax_myfilter` and the callback is `misha_filter_function()`.
2. The `Content-Type` header doesn't match the request body and you should've used `application/json` instead of `text/html`.

But then, even with the correct request body and headers, the `admin-ajax.php` doesn't actually support JSON request, so if you want to send JSON *request*, then you should use the WordPress REST API and you'd probably want to [add a custom endpoint like `my-plugin/v1/myfilter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

Otherwise, and if you prefer using the `admin-ajax.php`, then for example, you can use the [`FormData()` API in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) to properly build the form data to be sent to `admin-ajax.php`:

```js
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append( 'action', 'myfilter' );
formData.append( 'test', 'foo bar baz' );

fetch( url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
} ) // wrapped
    .then( res => res.text() )
    .then( data => console.log( data ) )
    .catch( err => console.log( err ) );
```

Comment: Ahh, I pass wrong action name. Now it's working. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give me an example how to build custom endpoint to post multipart form data? I am new to Wordpress and I trying to integrate React form with WP.

Comment: @Frostbourn it's not that I can't, but you should instead post your own question and not asking here.. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you for the response. I already have done that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/395462/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-to-wordpress-endpoint

Comment: ty @SallyCJ I was looking everywhere for this :D

Answer (score 2):

I think below is the most convenient way to initiate an ajax request via javascript fetch API. Creating WordPress ajax requests without jQuery.

```php
// PHP WP ajax hook
add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxCallback', 'ajaxCallback');
```

```js
//  Creating data 
let requestData = {
    action: "ajaxCallback",
    myData: "Your data",
    nonce: 'test nonce'
};
    
// Initiating AJAX request 
fetch('http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
    method:"post",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: new URLSearchParams(requestData).toString(),
}).then(function(response) {
    // return response.json(); // if responce is in json.
    return response.text();
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```