# How to send multipart form data to WordPress endpoint

Tags: forms, rest-api, endpoints

I built custom React/Gatsby multipart form with file upload and I want to send all form data to WordPress endpoint, upload files to specific folder and display all of the data in the WordPress backend.

This is how I send data:

```
const {
    stepOne,
    stepTwo,
  } = useContext(FormStepProvider)

  const steps = {
    stepOne: stepOne,
    stepTwo: stepTwo,
  }

  const postData = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData()

    formData.append("stepOne", JSON.stringify(stepOne))
    formData.append("stepTwo", stepTwo.file)

    await fetch("https://panel.domain.com/wp-json/test/v1/forms", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },

      body: formData,
    })
      .then(response => response)
      .then(result => {
        console.log("Success:", result)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error:", error)
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    postData()
    console.log(steps)
  }, [])
```

This is the response I get:
[image]

This is my endpoint:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'test/v1', 'forms', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'get_formdata_function',
    'args'     => array(),
  ) );
} );

function get_formdata_function(WP_REST_Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->get_body();
    print_r($data);
}
```

I'm new to WordPress and I want to know what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't know what `stepTwo.file` is, but I presumed it's a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object instance, and I believe the issue here is that you're not aware that you didn't actually need to manually set the `Content-Type` header because when the request body is a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance, then the content type header will always default to `multipart/form-data`.

Therefore just get rid of that header from the `headers` list in your `fetch()` call and then in your endpoint callback, use [`WP_REST_Request::get_file_params()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_REST_Request/get_file_params/) to get the uploaded file data (name, temporary path, size, etc.). So for example, you could do `$request->get_file_params()['stepTwo']`. (`$_FILES['stepTwo']` would also work, but I'd use the class method)

As for the `stepOne` parameter (which would be stored in the `$_POST` array), you could simply do `$request['stepOne']` to get the value, or you could also do `$request->get_param( 'stepOne' )`.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments for more details.

Additionally, you should always set [`permission_callback`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback), so for example if your REST API endpoint is public, you could do `'permission_callback' => '__return_true'`.